# Is it possible to integrate websockets with Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

The idea is simple. I have a websocket server which sends me comma separated value. I would want to use Google Sheets to render the data and at the same time, use the power of sheets. 
Is such a integration possible?

Note- I know that integrating with a REST API is possible,but I am more interested on live update of data and that too without long polling and other mechanism. I already have a websocket API ready which sends data,just want to know if I can use Google sheets as the client.

If it is possible then how?

Comment: Why is the question unclear?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can keep an open websocket in apps scripts.

Maybe you can use a Apps Scripts trigger to run a routine (like cron).

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

In this routine you can access a web api.

It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use sheets API with node JS and socket IO.